# Pulling in frequent times from API with Alamofire in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I am new to Swift, and I would like to pull from the API using the get request every 5 seconds, I have done the HTTP request pulling and parsing. I just would like to know where should I put some kind of loop in my controller class.

This is my controller class code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class HomePageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var age: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getRequest()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    // the function that get Request from the API
    func getRequest(){
        AF.request("http://vocation.cs.umd.edu/flask/tempjson", method: .get)
                    .responseJSON { (response) in
                        do{
                            let json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
                            let nm = json["username"].string
                            let ag = json["age"].int
                            let em = json["email"].string
                            // display
                            self.name.text = "Welcome, \(nm ?? "")"
                            self.age.text = "Age: \(ag ?? 0)"
                            self.email.text = "Email: \(em ?? "")"
                            
                        } catch let jsonErr{
                            print(jsonErr)
                        }
                    }
    }

}
```

I know I put the pulling function in `viewDidLoad()`, but where do I put to execute this function when staying at this page at a frequency of 5s, and what kind of loop can I use to make sure it is every 5 s doing this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to make a call every 5 seconds you can use a scheduled timer

```
class HomePageViewController: UIViewController {
 
    // ...
    
    var timer: Timer?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (timer) in
            self?.getRequest()
        })
        
        getRequest() // Call it initially because the scheduledTimer will only call it after the initial 5 seconds
    }
    
    func getRequest() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I would suggest waiting for the response of the request tho (with bad internet it can happen that requests take longer than 5 seconds and you would end up with "overlapping" requests.

Here a solution where a request is performed 5s after the response

```
class HomePageViewController: UIViewController {
 
    // ...
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        getRequest()
    }
    
    func getRequest() {
        AF.request("http://vocation.cs.umd.edu/flask/tempjson", method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
            do{
                let json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
                let nm = json["username"].string
                let ag = json["age"].int
                let em = json["email"].string
                // display
                self.name.text = "Welcome, \(nm ?? "")"
                self.age.text = "Age: \(ag ?? 0)"
                self.email.text = "Email: \(em ?? "")"
                
            } catch let jsonErr{
                print(jsonErr)
            }
            
            // Trigger a new request 5s after the response
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5, execute: { [weak self] in
                                            self?.getRequest()
            })
        }
    }
}
```